# Systems Programming: Fork()

Tags: c, fork

I have provided code for a problem that involves fork. However I am at a tough spot figuring out a few key parts to the program. The problem states for me to Check the appropriate command-line argument and output a usage message if the command line
is incorrect. Initialize pr_limit from the command line. The pr_limit variable specifies the maximum number of children allowed to execute at a time.The pr_count variable holds the number of active children. Initialize it to 0. Execute the following main loop until the end-of-file is reached on standard input: If pr_count is pr_limit, wait for a child to finish and decrement pr_count. Read a line from standard input (fgets) of up to MAX_BUF characters and execute a program corresponding to that command line by forking a child and execute the file. Increment pr_count to track the number of active children. Check to see if any of the children have finished (**). Decrement pr_count for each child that has completed. After encountering end-of-file on standard input, wait for all of the remaining children to finish
and then exit. For each terminated child, prints out its exit code value.

The portion that I am having trouble implementing involves reading line from standard file and executing a program corresponding to the command line by forking. As well as keeping track of the active children and  checking if children has finished. Still fairly new to systems programming.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("testsim.c", "r+");

    pid_t childpid;
    childpid = fork();

    int len = 0;
    char *line = NULL;

    read = getline(&line, &len, file);
    MAX_BUF = read;
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    int i, pr_limit;
    int pr_count = 0;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s processes\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
    }

    if (childpid == 0)
    {
            while (!feof(file))
            {
                    if (pr_count == pr_limit)
                    {
                            wait(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
                            pr_count--;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                            fgets(buf, MAX_BUF, file);
                    }
                            pr_limit = atoi(argv[1]);
                            for (i = 0; i < pr_limit; i++)
                            {
                                    if ((childpid = fork()) <= 0)
                                            break;
                            }

                    fprintf(stderr, "i: %d process ID: %ld parent ID: %ld child ID: %ld\n", i, getpid(), getppid(), childpid);
            }
    }

    if (pid < 0)
    {
            perror("Error: \n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: `if (argc != 2)` - shouldn't you be doing that *before* you fork. Seems pointless to stand up another process when neither get past that condition if its triggered and they both exit.

Comment: @WhozCraig i thought that i called the fork after the if(argc != 2), was it done incorrectly??